# Is it possible to select ISE variant of a logic app connector when developing in Visual Studio?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to select ISE variant of a logic app connector when developing in Visual Studio?

Trying the Logic App extension for VS 2019 and it seems to be working

Now trying to use it for a logic app which is deployed into our ISE

If I use the Portal, I can select either the standard connector, OR the ISE variant, e.g. the SQL Server and Key Vault ones.

In VS 2019, I can't see any of the ISE variants?

Comment: Did you find any way or solution? I am also looking for same.

Comment: @samash Sorry, I've not worked with logic apps since the end of January, so I can't remember if I found a solution  :-(

Comment: ok ok . thanks for you response @SteveC